# File size and screen recording

Tags: video

First and foremost, I would like an academic reference on how screen recording "works."
I have tried searching online, but I only get results for the software itself.

Exactly how does screen recording work, and to what extent does the content one records effect filesize?
For instance, if I were to record my screen playing an (x) resolution video, would the final output size be proportionally larger? Why or why-not?

If this question is closed, please, I would appreciate a reference, or a better way to phrase it (or a referral to a more appropriate sub-forum).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, screen recording works by taking a screenshot of the screen many times per second.  Taking a screenshot works by taking a copy of what is displayed on the screen.  To understand how that works, you need to understand how things are displayed on the screen; for that, I recommend reading about [framebuffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer).  The screen capture might then be stored in a compressed or uncompressed format.  The file size will be influenced by the resolution of the screen, the length of the video, and what compression is used (if any).